# PHP/MySQL: Footer displayed before table (powered by a database)

Tags: php, sql

On my page, I have a table (content from MySQL) and a footer (using require_once()).

The problem is, even though the "require_once("footer.php");" line of code is after my table display code, the footer is displayed above my table.

Here's my code:

```
$table='mytable';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

//echo "<h1>Table: {$table}</h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
// printing table rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";

    // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    // of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>

<?
    require_once("footer.php"); 
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not closing the table tag after the loop constructing the table.

```
  echo "</table>";
```

Place that after the while loop.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I must've missed that table tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to close the table tag:

```
 mysql_free_result($result);
 echo "</table>"
 require_once("footer.php"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are closing the `</table>` tag.

Also, this may be an issue with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your closing tag for table?

Put this

```
echo "</table>";
```